# Speed4j Vs Perf4j

Tags: java, performance

Speed4j and perf4j, both are Java performance analysis tools are similar in nature.

If I am looking for Speed4j document, I am geting following information:

> This is Speed4j, a very simple (but fast) Java performance analysis
>   library. It is designed using Perf4j as a model, but hopefully
>   avoiding the pitfalls inherent in Perf4j's design.  Also, Perf4j does
>   not seem to be seeing a lot of development these days.

But not sure what is the meaning of "avoiding the pitfalls inherent in Perf4j's design", What are perf4j pitfalls?

Comment: I had exactly the same question reading the speed4j documentation.

Comment: I've registered an issue on the speed4j site: https://github.com/jalkanen/speed4j/issues/20

Answer (score 9):

I had three reasons for starting Speed4J:

1. Avoid String parsing. Perf4j architecture sends measurements through Log4j encoded inside Strings, which are then parsed. The String creation/parsing causes unnecessary GC overhead.
2. Provide shutdown hooks. Perf4j cannot be cleanly shut down in a web container because it starts threads and provides no way to access them - so there's a memory leak.  There was a long-standing bug in Perf4j on that, and I got frustrated because nothing happened.
3. No development.  Bugs were unanswered, no new releases were being made.

I thought about forking Perf4j because of 2 and 3, but in the end point 1 made me start my own project so that I and others could hopefully take it further.  Perf4j was a great project though, I loved it :-)

Comment: I do not know an answer but do you know about this article?

http://www.infoq.com/articles/perf4j

Maybe at least a part of your question gets answered there.